# Properly using functions in a JS library

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, scope

Right now I am attempting to build a JavaScript library, albeit, it is very juvenile and I'm sure that it can be reworked to perform better. However, I'm currently storing some of my more common functions that I routinely use (while rendering HTML5 Canvas animations) and I have aforementioned JavaScript functions stored within their own flat file named canvasLab.js. My current structure is this:

```
var canvasLab = {

     setCanvas: function(elem) {
        if (elem == undefined) {
            return Modernizr.canvas;
        }
        return document.getElementById(elem);
    },

    set2D: function(elem) {
        return elem.getContext('2d');
    },
```

... and everything works fine until I attempt to declare a function within another function:

```
    getColorGradient: function(freqR,freqG,freqB,phaseA,phaseB,phaseC,center,width,length) {
        if (center  == undefined) center = 128;
        if (width == undefined) width = 127;
        if (length  == undefined) length = 50;
        colorArray=[];
        frequency = 0.3;
        amplitude = 127;
        center = 128;
        byte2Hex: function(n) {
        nybHexString = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        return String( nybHexString.substr( ( n >> 4 ) & 0x0F, 1 ) ) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F, 1);
        },
        getRgb: function(r,g,b) {
        return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
        },
        getGradientArray: function() {

            for (var i=0; i<length; ++i) {

                red = Math.sin(freqR * i + phaseA) * width + center;
                green = Math.sin(freqG * i + phaseB) * width + center;
                blue = Math.sin(freqB * i + phaseC) * width + center;

                result = getRgb(red,green,blue);
                this.colorArray[i] = result;
            }

     }

}
```

when I receive an 'unexpected token (' error at line 45:

```
 byte2Hex: function(n) {
```

I'm sort of new to making JavaScript libraries (or Lib Objects), and I am still unsure about the best method(s) and syntax to use while developing a library. My hugest concern is that it is light weight internally, on the client's machine and in the browser. In either case, I do not understand why I cannot create a new method (i.e.: byte2Hex()) and have it instantiated through the parent object. Any criticism would surely be appreciated.

Comment: byte2Hex: function(n) should be byte2Hex =  function(n)

Comment: Seriously, please learn about declaring local variables with `var`.  You are using a whole bunch of implicit global variables which is a really bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are defining your function as if it was in scope of an object

```
byte2Hex: function(n)
```

This line should say

```
byte2Hex =  function(n)....
```

These two functions below also have the same issue

If you want to return them as methods then they should be wrapped in an object.

```
 return {
        getRgb: function(r,g,b) {
            return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
        },
        getGradientArray: function() {//...
        }
        };
```

You also have a ton of references that are not scoped using the var statement.

To help you find, track these types of errors try pasting your code into:

http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: Yes, I was not defining the function within the proper scope. That totally fixed my problem, and I sincerely appreciate it.  - Cheers